# Running functions in intervals

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to animate a set of elements (`.col-n`) in intervals. Let's say I have four `.col` elements (`.col-1` etc) and I want to animate each of them class, but not after one is complete, but earlier.

I tried doing some `for` with `setInterval`, but it's not working (it's just looping):

```
    container.children('.col').last().on('click', function() {
        for(var i = 1; i <= columns; i++) {
            var int = self.setInterval(function() {
                console.log('a')
            },500*i)
        }
    });
```

I tried `each` from jQuery with this and it's not this also. Can someone point me to right direction?

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/s5DMe/

Please note that I don't want to run functions one after another, but run one, wait (no matter if the first one has finished or not), run another one.

Comment: Can you please create a jsfiddle..?

Comment: 1) use window instead of self, 2) do NOT alert but use console to show values

Comment: How is that a duplicate ?

Comment: I've added jsFiddle link.

@undefined it's not duplicate, since I want to run functions while others are running in the meaintime (eg. run function that lasts 1s, and after 500ms run another one).

Comment: @TomekBuszewski Please explain what exactly should happen.

Comment: Most simple explanation that comes to mind:
start! after 200ms function '.col-1-func1' starts, after another 200ms '.col-2-func2' starts. But I don't want to write setInterval` for each element.

Answer (score 0):

```
.col-1 { background: #ccffff; transition-delay: 200ms }

.col-2 { background: #b3ffff; transition-delay: 400ms }

.col-3 { background: #99ffff; transition-delay: 600ms }

.col-4 { background: #80ffff; transition-delay: 800ms }
```

You can add your animating class to all of the `.col-*`'s at the same time. The `transition-delay` handles the faux sequencing.

Of course, you'll need to add the browser-prefixed versions of the property as well.

Comment: Please post an example. I want to run `addClass` (css animations). I made this in the loop `$('.col-'+i).delay(500*i).addClass('act')` and it ran altogether.

Comment: Ahhh I see - I thought you wanted to use jquery animate. In this case, try adding the `tansition-delay` property to each corresponding `.col-*` class.

Comment: What's with the voting? This was a perfectly reasonable answer based on the information provided. He specifically used the words `jquery` and `animate`, did he not?

Comment: Please post an example.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, made it by myself ;) It was all the matter of using the interval and then creating a pseudo-loop inside:

```
    container.children('.col').last().on('click', function() {
        var i = 0;
        setInterval(function() {
            if(i != 4) {
                i++;
                $('.col-'+i).addClass('act')
            }
        },500)
    });
```

Thanks anyway :)

Comment: So, instead of using the existing css `transition-delay`, you're recreating it's sole purpose in javascript?

Comment: Since I wanted all-js solution, yes. Plus, I don't have to write css for each `.col`, the fiddle css was just an example.